# controller and module with same name

Tags: yii

I have controller and module with same name: download

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'http://'.SITE_DOMAIN.'/<action:(download)>/<url:.*>'=>'<action>',
        'http://<module:(download)>.'.SITE_DOMAIN.'/<code:\w{32}>'=>'<module>',
    ),
)
```

So I want to links like: http://domain.com/download/dir1/dir2/file1.zip

to be routed to: application/controllers/DownloadController

where $_GET['url']=='dir1/dir2/file1.zip'

And links like: http://download.site.com/some_code

to be routed to: application/modules/download/controllers/DefaultController.php

where $_GET['code']=='some_code'

But now both types of links are routed to: application/modules/download/controllers/DefaultController.php

I can't understand why

Comment: please show SITE_DOMAIN in http://site.com/ and http://download.site.com/. And move forward `'http://<module:(download)>.'.SITE_DOMAIN.'/<code:\w{32}>'=>'<module>',` as first element in rules array

Comment: I use constant for different domains like site.com and site local.

Comment: I've tried to move subdomain rule at first place, and got the same result

Comment: Check and show your constant definition

Comment: define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'site.com'); I have a lot of rules, all of them work proparly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'http://'.SITE_DOMAIN.'/download/<url:.*>'=>'Download/index',
        'http://download.'.SITE_DOMAIN.'/<code:\w{32}>'=>'Download/Default/index',
    ),
)
```

Note: both URLs will be routed to the index action of they own controller.